# counting the number of leaves with a certain property for each subtree (binary search tree)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree with integer labels.
I have to count the leaves with this property (I'll call it property x): the father has an even (odd) label and the leaf has an odd (even) label;  then I have to store this number in the node. I have to do this for each subtree.
In the end I have to print that number for each node.

For example, if i have  [this tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GyvC.png), the output should be the one on the left(with an in-order visit).

This is my struct (L is the number of leaves that satisfy the property x for that node)

```
struct node {
int label;
node*right;
node*left;
int L;
};
```

these are the functions i have written so far.

```
void addnodeBST(node*&tree, int l) { //adds a node
if (!tree) {
    tree = new node;
    tree->label = l;
    tree->right = tree->left = 0;
    tree->L = 0;
    return;
    }
if (l < tree->label)
    addnodeBST(tree->left, l);
if (l > tree->label)
    addnodeBST(tree->right, l);
}

int counter(node*tree) { //counts how many leaves are there
    if (!tree)
        return 0;
    if (!tree->left && !tree->right)
        return 1;
    return counter(tree->left) + counter(tree->right);
}

void updateL(node*tree) { //updates tree->L for each node
    if (tree) {
        tree->L = counter(tree);
        if (!tree->right && !tree->left)
            tree->L = 0;
        updateL(tree->left);
        updateL(tree->right);
    }
}

void printree(node*tree) { //prints L for each node
    if (tree) {
        printree(tree->left);
        cout << tree->L << endl;
        printree(tree->right);
    }
}
```

The function "counter" counts every leaf, but I don't know how to modify it to make it count only the leaves that satisfy the property x.
Could you help me?

EDIT:I'm probably not explaining well the property, I'll try to reforumale.
A leaf is to be counted if its label is even AND its father's label is odd,or if its label is odd AND its father's label is even.

Comment: Introduce a conditional `if` statement where appropriate. What is `property x`? This might be better suited for [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A leaf satisfies property x if  its label is even and its father's label is odd, or if its label is odd and its father's label is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a `std::function` parameter for your `counter()` function that is used to determine if a leaf should be counted or not:

```
int counter(node*tree, 
            std::function<bool (const node*)> check = [](const node*){ return true}) 
{
    if (!tree)
        return 0;
    if (!tree->left && !tree->right && check (tree))
        return 1;
    return counter(tree->left) + counter(tree->right);
}
```

You can use the function like

```
int count = counter(tree,[](const node* node) 
      { return !(node->label % 2); } // count only leafs with even label property
      );
```

---

Maybe rename the function to `count_leaf_if()`.

Comment: probably i'm not explaining well. I have to count only leaves with even label whose father has  an odd label or leaves with odd label whose father has an even label.

Comment: @DumbWrench That way you can implement any condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify your `printree` function with a conditional `if` statement that checks for an odd or even `label` property (modulo arithmetic).  If it's `true`, print the data `L` out, else print `0`.

An example snippet might be:

```
if (tree->label % 2 == 0) // if the label property is even
    std::cout << tree->L << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
```

Make sure that ONLY the `cout` statement is part of your `if` statement, you still need to make sure you get to all your recursive calls.